# Git Clone Not Working - No Error Message

Tags: macos, git, github, https, clone

I have just created a github account and made my first `HelloWorld` repository. I am trying to clone it onto my local machine like how they teach in the tutorial link provided below. This is what I get when I type in the command like what is shown in the tutorial.

```
bash-3.2$ git clone https://github.com/cameronpattisall/HelloWorld.git
Cloning into 'HelloWorld'...
^C
bash-3.2$
```

It will just continue so say `Cloning into 'HelloWorld'`... until I control C to quit out of the command. Does anyone know why this is occurring or what I may be doing wrong?

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: GitHub has been under DDoS recently, and probably still is. Just try again later.

Comment: If you have a proxy in your network, it also can be the problem.